# AWS EC2 is able to connect to external traffic ONLY with IP. DNS does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, ping, outbound, web-traffic, external-url

After login to my EC2 instance, I m unable to hit any website and I get the below error:

```
git clone -b release/development https://myadmin:WyuamrLnFVZKxCqfdf@bitbucket.org/dkteam/vida_ui.git temp

fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/dkteam/vida_ui.git/': Could not resolve host: bitbucket.org
```

Likewise, ping google.com does not work but pinging google.com's IP address works

```
ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

V/S

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-42-237:/var/www/html/apps/vidad/ui$ ping 172.217.160.174
PING 172.217.160.174 (172.217.160.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.217.160.174: icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=247 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.160.174: icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=247 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.160.174: icmp_seq=3 ttl=49 time=247 ms
```

Below is my security group outbound settings:

[image]

Below is VPC details:

[image]

[image]

Here is the route table:

[image]

Finally here is the firewall status:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-42-237:/var/www/html/apps/vidad/ui$ sudo ufw status
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-172-31-42-237: Temporary failure in name resolution
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
8069                       ALLOW       Anywhere
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8069 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Kindly suggest as this was working earlier.

Comment: I disabled `ufw` yet the problem persists.

Comment: Restarting the EC2 instance seems to have resolved this issue. We can close this issue.

Comment: If you think your question will not help future readers, you can **delete** this Question yourself.